# Footer issues: Can't extend to edges of window

Tags: html, window, footer

I can't seem to get my footer to extend to left and right edges of the browser window. I've been trying everything, but I can't get it to work. How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Vague question: no tag for HTML or CSS (we can guess because you mention browser, but that's bad for question identification), no indication of what a footer is in your design (is that an HTML5 footer?), not showing what you have tried so far, etc.

Comment: I'm just testing it out. I mean CSS. Sorry. That text I have is just for testing code out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it to your css:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With no HTML or CSS to accompany the question, I'd have to say that your footer it inside of another container (`<div id="page-wrap">` anyone?) that has a margin and/or padding applied.